# Why does typescript widens a property's type even when explicitly set?

Tags: typescript

Consider this simple piece of code that defines an interface for a `Person` and then creates an object of that type:

```js
interface Person {
    name: string | number
}

const john: Person = {
    name: "John"
}
```

Now I'd expect `john.name` to be a `string`. However, to my surprise it seems the type of this property [remains widened as a union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=7&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwE4FN1QBRgIYC26AXIgM5SoxjICUiA3gFCKuIQJlwA26AdNzjJsAAwAS6boMQASBviIBfEbSaKmTAPSbEAWn0HDR4ydNndG6lHSpgeCOkQAFG1yTM2iBSXKVqyRAAfLxACACMbNQ0OMApEACs4AAswUhdUN0QAXkYWNm9SACIAKWSwQqimNEwcRJS+b3ptRABBVGRQ9DAoRDhgRCgATwAHRwByCioaIJDwmzHEGDIvOB68MjIYZHww3gG4RGG8VEIsG17+odHECb8aMb48z2eX5tYAFRHxsFCI1AWlis1hstjs9lADldxpN-A9sAAmADMABYAKyqIA) even after being assigned a `string`:

```
function greet(name: string) {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
}

greet(john.name) // Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
                 //   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
```

I even tried to force the compiler to see the light by forcing `name`'s type to be `string` but to no avail:

```
const john: Person = {
    name: "John" as string
}

greet(john.name) // Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
                 //   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
```

Can someone shed some light on this behavior?

Comment: Question is why you'd expect it to narrow the type here, by writing `: string | number` you told TS that this property can be either string or number. TS does static type checking, thus it will apply this rule whenever it finds a `Person.name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you're wondering why your example fails:

```
const john: Person = {
    name: "John"
}
greet(john.name) // error!
// -> ~~~~~~~~~  "(string | number) is not assignable to string"
```

while the following works:

```
const name: string | number = "John";
greet(name); // okay
```

or this:

```
john.name = "Still John";
greet(john.name); // okay
```

---

[Control flow type analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) is a feature of TypeScript whereby the type checker can deduce that a variable of some wider type can temporarily be regarded as being of some narrower type.  So if I have a variable `name` declared to be type `string | number`, I'm allowed to assign any `string` or `number` to it:

```
name = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0.007 : "James Millibond";
```

But the following works without type assertions:

```
console.log(typeof name === "string" ? name.toUpperCase() : name.toExponential(0)); 
// 7e-3 or JAMES MILLIBOND
```

In the `name.toUpperCase()` part of the code, the compiler has narrowed the type of `name` to  `string` and in the `name.toExponential(0)` part of the code, the compiler has narrowed the type of `name` to `number`.  This is control flow analysis in action.

And when you *assign* a value of type `string` or `number` to a variable of type `string | number`, the compiler will narrow the type of that variable to either `string` or `number` until you assign a new value to the variable.  This is also due to control flow analysis.

---

And an important restriction on TypeScript's control flow analysis: only **union** types are narrowed.  **If a variable is not of a union type, it will not be narrowed.** And while `string | number` is a union type, `Person` is not.  Yes, the `name` property of `Person` *is* of a union type, but that doesn't make `Person` a union type.

So assigning `john` itself doesn't do any narrowing, but assigning `john.name` does.

---

Why doesn't the compiler narrow non-union types?  The closest to a canonical answer I can find is in [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8513#issuecomment-217871478) by the implementer of the control flow analysis algorithm:

> The question of narrowing non-union types on assignment is one that we're still thinking about. It gets somewhat more complicated because ... when optional properties are involved, the assigned type may actually have fewer members than the declared type.

There is an [open issue (microsoft/TypeScript#16976)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16976) suggesting that control flow analysis narrowing be applied to non-union types as well.  If you feel strongly about this, you might want to go give that issue a  and/or describe your use case if you think it's compelling.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: Indeed that's what I was wondering about. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript widens the type to give an error for this code:

```
interface Person {
    name: string | number
}

const john: Person = {
    name: "John"
}

john.name = 0

function greet(name: string) {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
}

greet(john.name)
```

The type of `john` is only checked to be `Person`.

Answer (score -1):

### Parameter issue

I think your error come from this function:

```
function greet(name: string) {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
}
```

For the parameter, you defined as `string` only, but your type is `string | number`

Do the following and it will fix the error:

```
function greet(name: string | number) { // add number here =)
    console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
}
```

#### How it runs

When you run either of this, it will work:

```
const john: Person = {
    name: "John"
};

const sam: Person = {
    name: 1
};
```

Output:

```
greet(john.name); // Hello John
greet(sam.name); // Hello 1
```