# Extending a dynamic object without loosing access to literal keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to have an object that has an initial set of keys that is extendable by the library user through a function. How would I archieve this without loosing access to the  union of all valid keys? Things like `Record<string, number>` are too generic and result in `keyof typeof obj`: `string`

In this example, is it possible to type `obj` so that after calling `addSomething` and reassigning the return value to `obj`, `keyof typeof obj` returns `'a' | 'b' | 'x'`?

```
const initialObj = { a: 1, b: 2 } // this is passed by the library user

type ObjType<T> = {
  [readonlykey in keyof T]: number
}

let obj = initialObj // How would I type this?

function addSomething(): ObjType<typeof obj> & { x: number } {
  return {
    ...obj,
    x: 1
  }
}

const newAssignment = addSomething() // this works
obj = addSomething() // but this doesn't

// This is still: 'a' | 'b'
// I want validKeys to be: 'a' | 'b' | 'x'
type validKeys = keyof typeof obj
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgJZSXJBDANgeQEYBWCAvAgN4IYBcCAjADQJ40BMCAvqKHAJ4AOAUwT4CAFX4CAPKIB8JcqAQIA2gCcBGACbQsPANYCeyKAgM8IAMwSiAujSgBXALZ4Bq0JxCgsAxBELyKGiYuIRcIBYOUGDo0JSamgDKEE6+ABYoAOYAFACUNCLigpK8gpYI-gRyAGTkCAAe9s6uqhwKIErqcA6qJmSKSggAdCOV9ANKjXQDnp6gkLCIUAIA7gCCMDBImVCpUIikWkkp6Vl5CAD0FwhwGTAIKxCqejCglfJHyam3Z7mX13gHIgfvdtAIYFAAORwcJXax3ZD3eBILBYGiQjCQhAAHwQkLwkNAcIAkg8MPsEAA3bBITQAaUM9zgECYAnRmJxeIJnMh9UJIFKQmpWFpDJ491IZnKgvKlVAQA)

Comment: Assignments don't narrow the apparent types of variables of non-union types, so there's no way to make the line `obj = ...` do what you're looking for.  I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494636/why-does-typescript-widens-a-propertys-type-even-when-explicitly-set), unless you'd like to see a different approach entirely like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m04pam) shows.  Let me know how you'd like to proceed.

Comment: Interesting, thanks a lot! I'm open to that suggestion, although I'm not really sure I fully understand what's happening. Could you elaborate a little on why that `as any` is required?